# Weighted Coin Toss Probablity

Tags: probability

Suppose two weighted coins are tossed. The first is weighted so that it comes up heads with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. The second is weighted so that it comes up heads with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. What is the probability that when both coins are tossed, one comes up heads and the other comes up tails?

Comment: Try building a probability tree: HH, HT, TH, TT.

Comment: hint: p(A and B)=p(A)p(B) when A and B are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $P(HH)=\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}=\dfrac{1}{12}$
- $P(HT)=\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{3}{4}=\dfrac{1}{4}$
- $P(TH)=\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}=\dfrac{1}{6}$
- $P(TT)=\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{3}{4}=\dfrac{1}{2}$

So the answer to your question is $P(HT)+P(TH)=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{5}{12}$